# How can I define Map of String or Int in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Is there way to declare a Map that would accept both String and Int in Kotlin? Like:

```
var map: Map<String, String | Int>
```

Comment: Closest intersection between `String` and `Int` is `Any`.

Comment: What is your actual use case to require such a mix in the map's values? Wouldn't better types than ints and strings fit?

Comment: @Joffrey there are lots of use cases for Union Type (as they used in TypeScript for example). I wonder if they are also existed in Kotlin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no union type in Kotlin, so you can't directly express this.

A few options:

1. use `TreeMap<String, Any>`, which is the simplest of all, but it allows more types than just `Int` and `String`, and requires additional conversion boilerplate on the consumer side when accessing values.
2. use a custom `sealed class` to encapsulate your "`Int` or `String`" type, and use it in a regular `TreeMap<String, IntOrString>`. This will have some runtime overhead for wrapping/unwrapping the int/string objects for each insertion/access. Also, this puts the burden of (un)wrapping on the consumer side. That being said, maybe your domain can be better modeled with clearer names than `Int` or `String`, so it might actually improve the consumer's experience to define such types.
3. use a custom map type, with independent accessors for ints and strings, but backed by a single `TreeMap<String, Any>` behind the scenes. This has the advantage of encapsulating the logic and exposing a neat API for the consumers. If you extend `TreeMap` you will save some overhead as opposed to composition, but it shouldn't matter much.

I am wondering about the actual use case at hand, though. Usually the need for union types stems from using plain generic primitive types to represent meaningful domain data that could maybe better be expressed using more specific custom domain types.

Option 2 would therefore usually be my choice, but I would use a sealed class that actually represents my domain data instead of the generic "string or int".

Comment: Thanks. I was asking about a general case for modelling such case. I'm from TypeScript which has Union Type and wondered if similar capabilities are available in Kotlin. Seems like sealed classes are little like that although require more boilerplate.

Comment: +1 for “better… expressed using more specific custom domain types”.  In most cases, the best answer to this particular “How do I…?” question is “You don't.”  Patterns and techniques which are appropriate in languages with a weaker and/or less expressive type systems don't always translate well to Kotlin, where there are usually better approaches.  Use the type system, don't fight it!

Comment: @AlexCraft sealed classes is probably the closest you can get from TypeScript's union types. That being said, one major difference is that you have to define new custom types as part of the sealed class; you can't "unite" existing types like int or string. There were several discussions about introducing union types in Kotlin, but I'm not sure they will be considered again anytime soon, as they wouldn't have a proper representation on the JVM, and it would open the door for a lot of designs that Kotliners usually want to avoid.

Comment: @gidds type system in TypeScript is no weaker and or less expressive than typesystem in Kotlin. No need to call Kotlin disadvantage of not having union types as a positive thing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Any` here, see this example:

```kotlin
import java.util.TreeMap

fun main() {
    var map = TreeMap<String, Any>()
    map.put("One", 1)
    map.put("Two", "two")
    println(map)
}
```

which outputs

```
{One=1, Two=two}
```

**Please note:**
This will allow more types than just the desired `String` and `Int`, because [the Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/) state *(...). Every Kotlin class has Any as a superclass.*.

Comment: But it would also allow to add `map.put("One", listOf("error"))`

Comment: @AlexCraft yes, it does... This allows `Any`thing that is considered `Any` by kotlin.

Comment: maybe you can use [require](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html) to validate the types?